# Exterior derivative of a two-form as a divergence times the volume form

Tags: differential-forms

In a textbook, I have found the following relation.
$$
d \stackrel{2}{\omega_V} 
=
\frac{1}{3!} 
(\mathrm{div} V)
\epsilon_{ijk} 
dx^i \wedge dx^j \wedge dx^k .
$$
It is cool, but I don't know how to show it in an elegant way, please show me the way.

Here are definitions:

It is a relation in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$. There is a vector field in that space $V \in \Gamma (T\mathbb{R}^3)$. With the use of components of that vector, one can define a two-form
$$
\stackrel{2}{\omega_V} := \frac{1}{2} V^i \epsilon_{ijk} dx^j \wedge dx^k,
$$
where $\epsilon$ is completely antisymmetirc and $\epsilon_{123} =1$. Divergence of a vector is
$$
\mathrm{div}V = V^m_{\hphantom{mk},m} 
$$
where comma indicates partial derivative.

My attempt:

By taking the derivative of $\stackrel{2}{\omega_V}$ I get
$$
d\stackrel{2}{\omega_V} 
= 
\frac{1}{2} V^i_{\hphantom{m},l} \epsilon_{ijk} 
dx^l \wedge dx^j \wedge dx^k
$$
clearly, only terms where $i=l$ are non-zero. Consequently, by substituing $V^i_{\hphantom{m},l}$ with $V^i_{\hphantom{m},i}$ and dividing by  number of extra repetition which is $3$, I get what I want, but its v hand-wavy. Can someone can show me how to do in a decent way?

Comment: You did in a decent way, I think there is nothing to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a remark that
$$ dx^l \wedge dx^j \wedge dx^k = \epsilon^{ljk} {\rm vol} $$
where ${\rm vol} = \frac{1}{3!}\epsilon_{ijk}dx^i\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k$ is the volume form. Then use the fact that
$$ \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{ljk} = 2\delta^l_i$$
That may make the final transformations a bit smoother.